# Connection to SQL Server. Class not found. Jar is in JAVA_HOME. Telnet connects. Jar is in Lib also

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jtds

I have tried all of the answers listed here, as above. 
I am using `jtds-1.3.1.jar`.  It is `JAVA_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME/lib`. I have checked `env` variable. SQL Browser is running. **SQL AGENT** will not. Telnet connects.

```
String  driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
String url="jdbc:jtds:sqlexpress://MYPC:1433/DatabaseName=master;instance=SQLEXPRESS";
Class.forName(driver);
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "Daniel", "password");
System.out.println("Connected to the database!!! Getting table list...");
DatabaseMetaData dbm = conn.getMetaData();
rs = dbm.getTables(null, null, "%", new String[]{"TABLE"});
while (rs.next()) {
      System.out.println(rs.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
}
```

Comment: Putting a jar file into JAVA_HOME won't help. You need to add the jar file when running your application through the `-cp` parameter or your IDE's way of configuring it.

Comment: Besides getting your classpath sorted as suggested by a horse, your database URL is wrong, it should start with `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:`

Answer (score 0):

I should have mentioned I was using Android studio, but after some more searching I found out how to set dependencies in the IDE and that worked.
File->Settings->Build,Execution,Development->Compiler->Options= -cp

Comment: And fixed SQLEXPRESS err  - Thanks ALL